In HDL, why is combinatorial feedback (due to sensitivity list) a bad thing?
In one of my online lectures, it is said that the outptut should not be a part of the sensitivity list (as it would cause combinatonal feedback).
I am unable to understand why a combinational feedback is not desired. I have read that causes the circuit to be triggered continuously but would that be the case even in an ideal circuit with no delays?

because it would cause/imply combinatorial feedback, as your lecture said. Can you explain a bit what you don't understand about it? We can help you understand! But for that we would need to understand what you don't understand. Do you maybe not understand what a sensitivity list is? Or what "combinatorial feedback" is?

Adding an output signal to a sensitivity list will not by itself create feedback that isn't already in the body of the process. But it will cause unnecessary evaluations of the process during simulation.

This is a great question to ask the lecturer.  Good teachers love it when students pay attention and show interest.  Besides, you are spending a lot of money, and the teacher works for you.

@DaveTweed, Can you please explain how the unnecessary evaluations are caused. And if adding an output to the sensitivity list does not create feedback then how is the feedback created?

@MarcusMüller, I am unable to understand the combinational feedback part. I have edited my question explaining the same.

When a signal changes state, it creates an "event" in the simulator that triggers the re-evaluation of everything that signal touches. If you add that signal to the sensitivity list of a process, the process will be re-evaluated even if that signal is not used as an input inside the process.

@DaveTweed, this unnecessary evaluation would be once for each change in the input right (in the ideal scenario, where there are no delays)?

For each change of the output. And delays have nothing to do with it, only the fact that the signal has a change event.
